Why doesn't order-invariance increase the expressive power of first-order logic over arbitrary structures?
I’m currently working through Leonid Libkin’s Elements of Finite Model Theory in my spare time, and I find myself stuck on the following exercise:

Exercise 5.1. Prove that over arbitrary structures, $FO = (FO+<)_{inv}$.
(Hint: use the interpolation theorem)

This is supposed to stand in stark contrast to the case where only finite structures are considered, where it is more or less straightforward to construct a query that separates the two classes.
I think I understand why this result should be more or less unsurprising, given that (1) invariance is generally just a harder condition to satisfy the more structures you have to be invariant over and (2) unlike the finite case, there are lots of non-isomorphic ways to order infinite sets that make the first point much more acute. But this hardly constitutes even the beginnings of a proof.
Some further insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated. At the moment, I am unsure how to even apply the hint.

Can you explain the notation $(FO+<)_{inv}$?

Consider the languages $L_1 = L\cup \{<_1\}$ and $L_2 = L\cup \{<_2\}$. Note that $L_1\cap L_2 = L$.
Let $\varphi(<)$ be an $L\cup \{<\}$ sentence which is invariant under the interpretation of $<$ as a linear order.
Then by invariance, $\models(\text{"$<_1$ is a linear order"}\land \varphi(<_1))\to (\text{"$<_2$ is a linear order"}\to \varphi(<_2))$. By the Craig Interpolation Theorem, there is an $L$-sentence $\psi$ such that $\models (\text{"$<_1$ is a linear order"}\land \varphi(<_1))\to \psi$ and $\models \psi\to (\text{"$<_2$ is a linear order"}\to \varphi(<_2))$. Thus $\psi$ is equivalent to $\varphi(<)$ over structures linearly ordered by $<$.
